# How can I measure the gauge of stranded wire?

Tags: electrical

What is the best way to measure the gauge of stranded wire? I cannot tell between a 14 or 12 even though I have a standard awg gauge tool for solid wiring.

Comment: ...read the jacket.

Comment: See [Is there any way to easily and accurately determine the gauge of stranded wire by measuring it?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/70218/2191)

Answer (score 2):

Stranded wire is *a tick* bigger but it's certainly not *a whole size* bigger.  If stranded is sloppy-doppy in your #12 gage, it's #14.